# Increase week count by click

Tags: java, date, calendar, dayofweek

I want to increase by 1 week each click on a button and I want to show the first day of week at Jlabel1 and the end of week at JLabel2.

I have already done the first step displaying the first day knew Weeks and the last day (see code) but the 2nd step to INCREASE by 1 next week
for example this week (beginning> end 04-07-2016> 10-07-2016) and when I click on a button it augments by two weeks (beginning> end 11-07-2016> 17-07-2016)

```
 public void gestion_date() {
    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar maDate = new java.util.GregorianCalendar();
    maDate.setTime(date);
    // On se positionne sur le Lundi de la semaine courante :
    maDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
    dat = df.format(maDate.getTime());
    jLabel3.setText(dat);
    maDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
    dat = df.format(maDate.getTime());
    jLabel5.setText(dat);
}
```

[The screen of my Jlabel and button and the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNZfQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

The deleted Answer was correct. I do not understand why it was withdrawn.

## java.time

The Question uses troublesome old date-time classes that have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Much of the functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

You need a time zone to get the current date.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId );
```

Use [`TemporalAdjusters`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) to get the previous Monday. The [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) is a handy way to represent each of the seven days of the week.

```
LocalDate previousOrSameMonday = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) );
```

If you need the last day of your week for other purposes, you *could* do the following line. But for just the display as described in Question, no need to store this `nextSunday` object. You can always calculate it on the fly because you know it is always six days after the start of the week.

```
LocalDate nextSunday = previousOrSameMonday.with( TemporalAdjusters.next( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) );
```

Now you must store the starting day of the week in a member of a class, to stay around in memory. Local variables defined in your `gestion_date` method evaporate into nothingness upon completion of each execution. Somewhere you have a place to store the data currently being displayed in your Swing form. I do not know where that place is as you make no mention in your Question. So here I invent the fictional name `modelBehindMySwingForm` where “model” means “business data of my app”.

```
modelBehindMySwingForm.weekStart = previousOrSameMonday;
```

On each click of the addition or subtraction buttons, increment that member variable by a week.

```
modelBehindMySwingForm.weekStart = modelBehindMySwingForm.weekStart.plusWeeks( 1 ); // Or minusWeeks
```

And update the JLabel widgets with a String that represents the value of the `LocalDate` objects. You can obtain a [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format date by calling `toString`. Better would be letting java.time localize for you with [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). Store the formatter object somewhere such as on your `modelBehindMySwingForm`, as there is no sense in recreating it.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT );
formatter = formatter.withLocale( locale );
```

After incrementing `modelBehindMySwingForm.weekStart` as seen above, use the formatter to generate strings for display in your JLabel objects.

```
String start = modelBehindMySwingForm.weekStart.format( modelBehindMySwingForm.formatter );  // Monday
String stop = modelBehindMySwingForm.weekStart.plusDays( 6 ).format( modelBehindMySwingForm.formatter ); // Following Sunday.
```

Comment: what do u mean by (( modelBehindMySwingForm )) ??

Comment: Somewhere you have a place to store the data currently being displayed in your Swing form. I do not know where that is as you make no mention in your Question. So I invented the fictional name `modelBehindMySwingForm` where “model” means “business data of my app”.